# form_open() is not working peoperly

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have a controller named : user_login_controller.php and view : user_login_view.php
code of user_login_view.php

```
 <?php echo form_open('user_login_controller/login', 'class="form-horizontal" id="userloginform"');?>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Student Login</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-10">
          <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'rno','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Roll Number'])?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-10">
          <?php echo form_password(['name'=>'pwd','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Password'])?>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
          <?php echo form_reset(['name'=>'Reset','value'=>'Cancel','class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>
          <?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'Submit','value'=>'Login','class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

On submit button click I m sending control to user_login_controller/login
here is user_login_controller.php

```
<?php
class User_login_controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('user/user_login_view');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        echo "User login function";
    }
}
```

?>
but it's given me 404 error.however i have both files

and when I m going through url(http://localhost:8090/project/user_login_controller/login) :then its working. and i have loaded all the necessary helpers.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
```

what to do now?

Comment: What is this? "echo "User login function";" That will only echo out the words "echo "User login function";"

Comment: add `function __construct(){ }` missing in the above code before index function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `config['base_url']` in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8090/project/';
```

as `form_open` consider url to be set to `http://localhost:80/project/` or `http://[::1]/project/` if you didn't set `config['base_url']`

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps and it will sort-out the problem,

**1. View** 
when you opening a form tag, if you want to add several attributes, use this method.

```
<?php 
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'userloginform');
echo form_open('user_login_controller/login', $attributes);  
?>
```

It's clean and error less.

**2. Config.php**

Go to *application/config/config.php* file, and set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8090/your_project_folder_name/';
```

**3. routes.php**

Go to *application/config/routes.php* file, and set

```
$route['user_login_controller/(:any)'] = "user_login_controller/$1";
$route['user_login_controller'] = "user_login_controller";
```

This will work. Try it and let me know.